# How do I convert a wParam to a CString?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, cstring, postmessage

I have a `pMsg->wParam` from a WM_KEYDOWN message, and I want to convert it into a `CString`. How can I do that?

I have tried the following code:

```
TCHAR ch[2];
ch[0] = pMsg->wParam;
ch[1] = _T('\0');
CString ss(ch);
```

but it does not work for high ASCII characters.

Comment: wParam and lParam are used in different ways depending on the message being passed. What message are you receiving here? If it a regular windows message (eg. WM_GETTEXT) or a custom one (anything greater than WM_USER). Can you supply more code to show the message being send and received? (Note that PostMessage and strings don't usually play well together if the string is on the stack, since by the time the recipient window gets it, the caller's stack may have been unwound and reused, leaving the pointer invalid.)

Comment: @BrendanMcK i am using it on keystroke WM_CHAR basically, it is working fine on englisg language, but fails for language involving high ascii characters, may be the way i am terminating the TCHAR array is wrong for other languages

Comment: Do you have UNICODE and _UNICODE defined for your project? If you don't, when TCHAR will be just a plain single ANSI char, so odd things may happen (though I think it should still work with high ASCII, unless your are using different code pages or something...). With UNICODE and _UNICODE defined, it should (AFAIK) work for anything (er, anything that UTF16 supports). Also, when you try a high-ASCII key, are you seeing the expected value for wParam in the debugger?

Comment: unicode is defined in my project

Comment: Did you check the wParam value you are receiving in the message using the debugger? If it is incorrect in the first place, then there is no way of converting it to a correct string :)  Also, you mention 'postmessage' here - is this a normal WM_CHAR that is sent to your window as a result of a key press, or is it coming from other code?

Comment: it is coming from a key press , i have checked it on converting it into a TCHAR , TCHAR has correct value , i am now doing it with passing TCHAR directly in CString constructor, working for english have not checked with other languages or high ascii characters.TCHAR is however capable of storing them, but i want to know will there be some loss when i do TCHAR ch  = pMsg->wParam

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7784/discussion-between-peter-and-brendanmck)

Comment: Now that we know you're talking about `WM_CHAR`, it becomes evident how strange of a situation this is. Why in the world would you be combining `PostMessage` with `WM_CHAR`? Are you trying to send your own application keyboard messages to synthesize text input? That's not going to work. You need to use the `SendInput` function instead. Otherwise, if you just want to handle keyboard presses, you don't need `PostMessage` at all, you just add a handler for `WM_CHAR` to your main message loop. Strongly consider posting the relevant code in your question so we don't have to keep guessing.

Comment: Peter hasn't replied to the chat thread yet... But my guess: it might be working, but if he's using printf() or otherwise sending the string to the console, some conversion (ANSI/UNICODE to console code page) may be taking place when printing to the console that would not take place if the character was instead displayed in a MessageBox or other GUI means. What's really missing here is a statement of what the 'failure' is - where the string ends up afterwards.

Comment: hey guys the problem was i was capturing wparam on keydown and it was working fine for simple charachers but for high ascii wparam was having wrong value , i captured it on WM_CHAR . now it works fine on conerting it into a TCHAR and constructing CString directly from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `wParam` contains a *pointer* to an array of characters. It is not a single character, so you can't create the string yourself by assigning it to `ch[0]` as you're trying to do here.

The solution turns out to be a lot easier than you probably expected. The `CString` class has a constructor that takes a pointer to a character array, which is precisely what you have in `wParam`.
(Actually, it has [a bunch of constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx), one for pretty much everything you'll ever need...)

So all you have to do is:

```
CString ss(pMsg->wParam);
```

The constructor will take care of the rest, copying the string pointed to by `wParam` into the `ss` type.

Comment: @Peter, try `CString ss((LPCTSTR) pMsg->wParam);`.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi
the CString is always empty in this case

Comment: @Peter: The API function could be returning you an empty string. Use the debugger to see what the value of `pMsg->wParam` actually is before you start involving type conversion.

Comment: @CodyGray the conversion wents fine when i use the above Tchar method as mentioned in my question , but my method fails for languages other then english. but this method even fails for english

Comment: Sorry, but this is totally untrue. `WM_CHAR` sends a character in `wParam`, not a pointer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. This code worked probably because the constructor that takes a `wchar_t` was used in this case.

Comment: Interesting, I tried to figure out what exactly happens, but I could not compile that. I wrote
    `WPARAM w = 0x222D; CString cs (w);`
and got "error C2668: 'ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>::CStringT' : ambiguous call to overloaded function", in both 32 and 64 bit compile.

Comment: @kkm: Do note that my answer was written long before it was ever revealed in the comments that the message in question was `WM_CHAR`. The assumption I made was a very good one; just about every other window message sends a string of characters, rather than a single one.

Comment: @CodyGray: I was not at all implying that you did not know the subject matter. I am sorry if I sounded harsh or offensive--I did not truly mean it. But the answer as it stands sounds misleading (by way of editing the question, indeed).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `WM_CHAR` sends a character code in `wParam`. The first paragraph in the Remarks section says that the code is indeed a Unicode UTF-16 codepoint. This is true whether you are compiling your code for 8 or 16 bit `TCHAR`.

CodyGray's comment is correct in the part that `CString` supplies a variety of constructors. The one you are looking for is that which takes a `wchar_t` as its first argument (the second argument, the repetition count, is set to 1 by default). Therefore, to construct a `CString` out of a `WPARAM`, you cast the value to `wchar_t`. The following sample prints "0", confirming that the constructed string is indeed what it is expected to be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstringt.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
int main ()
{
  WPARAM w = 0x222D;
  CString cs ((wchar_t)w);
  printf ("%d", cs.Compare (L"\x222D"));
}
```

It will work the same in both _UNICODE and ANSI compilation modes, and is portable across 32 and 64 bitness.